# An implausibly plausible Collatz result. Should I believe the results of Reduce?

Tags: equation-solving

**Update 3** @azerbajdzan 's info in comment on OddQ explains the failure to find solutions, misinterpretation of which lead to the "implausibly plausible" conclusion. *However* repeated with Mod in place of OddQ, Reduce not produces (after LogicalExpand) 2592 conditions... all of which are manifestly unsatisfiable. I shall not pollute this question further with details of that; a new question will be asked.

**Update 1** -- the collatz formula has been corrected in the Sum[] part; the change did not alter the result of Reduce. See also Update 2 below for new doubts.

**Original**
Thanks to @bob-hanlon's answer to [How to specify and use indexed variables of undefined quantity?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275137/how-to-specify-and-use-indexed-variables-of-undefined-quantity), with the elimination of subscripted variables in favour of indexed variables, I am not able to instantly dismiss the result, despite its implausibility. One reason for doubting the result though is that there is no explicit restriction of n to positive integers, and there are solutions in the negative integers, but maybe something is implicitly limiting the Reduce to +ve integers.

In the question [Interpreting Reduce output (in the recreational context of the 3n + 1 problem)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275052/interpreting-reduce-output-in-the-recreational-context-of-the-3n-1-problem) I asked for help in interpreting the long and complex results of Reduce; that task is now rather different.

Note: the Collatz, a.k.a. 3 n + 1 problem concerns the iteration of the rules, if n is odd, multiply by three and add one, if n is even divide by two.

Every positive n ever iterated has fallen into the `{1, 4, 2}` cycle. Whether this is true for all n is unknown. Answering that (Terence Tao recently proved that ~it is almost always true, which was amazing, other results include, n is very large if there are other cycles and any such cycle must be very long) can be split into two: a) are there any other cycles?, or b) might the iterated sequence drift off to infinity.

By applying MMA to a closed form we obtain a specific answer to question a), which is surprising, to say the least. (And Update 2 below addresses question b) )

The questions are now:

1/ Is the following result a) true and b) if so, how could MMA's workings be inspected to confirm this manually?

2/ In the rather more likely event that the result is not true, what is wrong with the setup or MMA's workings, or how might I investigate the latter?

3/ Can anyone adapt the setup so it does identify the solutions n = -1, -5, -17?

Set up.

```
Format[q[n_]] := Subscript[q, n]
Q[n_] := 2^Sum[q[j], {j, 1, n}]
collatz[P_, n_] := (n (3^P ) +  3^(P - 1) + Sum[Q[i] 3^(P - i - 1), {i, 1, (P - 2)}] + Q[P - 1])/Q[P]

Reduce[collatz[P, n] == n && P >= 2 && OddQ[n], n, Integers, GeneratedParameters ->(Subscript[k, #] &) ]

(* False *)
```

(Understanding MMA's limitations and how to work with it better are implied goals of the questions above.)

**PS** Does collatz[P,n] even "Make sense?" (responding to @azerbajdzan)

These make perfect sense to me, and have the correct coefficients

```
collatz[2, n] == n // TeXForm
collatz[3, n] == n // TeXForm
collatz[4, n] == n // TeXForm
```

$2^{-q_1-q_2} \left(9 n+2^{q_1}+3\right) = n$

$2^{-q_1-q_2-q_3} \left(27 n+3\ 2^{q_1}+2^{q_1+q_2}+9\right) = n$

$2^{-q_1-q_2-q_3-q_4} \left(81 n+9\ 2^{q_1}+3\ 2^{q_1+q_2}+2^{q_1+q_2+q_3}+27\right)$

and this seems no less valid

```
collatz[7, -17] == -17 // TeXForm
```

$2^{-q_1-q_2-q_3-q_4-q_5-q_6-q_7} \left(243\ 2^{q_1}+81\ 2^{q_1+q_2}+27\ 2^{q_1+q_2+q_3}+9\ 2^{q_1+q_2+q_3+q_4}+3\
   2^{q_1+q_2+q_3+q_4+q_5}+2^{q_1+q_2+q_3+q_4+q_5+q_6}-36450\right)=-17$

in which case the question (ultimately) would be, what are the various $q_i$?

**Update 2**

A new reason for thinking there is something rotten in the state of Denmark is that `Reduce[collatz[P, n] (<, >) n && OddQ[n], ...]` are also False.

Comment: Your code has no sense. What is output of your function `collatz[P_, n_]` for concrete values of `P` and `n`?

Comment: "the question (ultimately) would be, what are the various $q_i$?" What prevents you from computing them? - You know the Collatz algorithm and know the starting point `-17`. Where is the problem?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Yes, of course. The question is about Reduce in the symbolic form; I only put that in because you said the code had no sense -- it shows how it makes sense and shows the remaining putative "unknowns". The problem is Reduce, symbolically and the fact that it doesn't find that case.

Comment: `OddQ` gives `False` for non-numeric expressions. So it means `OddQ[n]` immediately evaluates to `False` and that is why Reduce outputs `False` without even looking at equation `collatz[P, n] == n`. Correct way of expressing oddity of `n` is `Mod[n, 2] == 1`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan You are absolutely right about OddQ (and EvenQ...)! They only apply to expressions with Head Integer! It is annoying that the information is hidden in the docs under details, and I can see no reason for such a limitation when it could automatically used Mod or Divisible if the Head is not Integer. That makes an interesting difference - now Reduce gives longer output. Thank you.

Comment: @JulianMoore, just a note: This is true for all "Q" functions :) They are [designed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TestingExpressions.html) to always _immediately_ evaluate to either True or False.

Comment: @Domen Thx. Looked that up. 'Functions that "ask a question" have names that end in Q. They return True for an explicit true answer, and False otherwise'. Do you know where this meaning of "explicit" is given? And what's the difference between that and "manifestly" used elsewhere re Q functions?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Your info in comment effectively answers the bulk of the question, so if you wish to provide a formal answer I would accept it.

Comment: You can answer your own question too and then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** The postulated result  of Reduce is not to be believed because the core element of the collatz function has no effect in the presence of OddQ applied to a symbolic argument (for which, see the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OddQ.html)). Use Mod[] instead. The OP was probably misled by *Confirmation Bias* re the positive integers (and even more confused by the absence of solutions in negative integers).

**Full Form**

The application of Reduce

```
Reduce[collatz[P, n] == n && P >= 2 && OddQ[n], n, Integers, GeneratedParameters ->(Subscript[k, #] &) ]

(* False *)
```

is independent of the equations `collatz[P, n] == n && P >= 2` because, as pointed out by @azerbajdzan, the behaviour of `OddQ` and its ilk is unusual, especially in the context of symbolic manipulation - as here - where it will always return False.

**In order to use oddness or similar in Reduce, one should use Mod[].**

As to the operation of OddQ, further clarity is desirable. It says in the documentation for [OddQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OddQ.html)

> gives True if expr is an odd integer, and False otherwise.

However, one should attend to the Detail (which is normally collapsed and so not immediately visible), where it says

> OddQ[expr] returns False unless expr is manifestly an odd integer
> (i.e. has head Integer, and is odd).

The adverb *manifestly* is important: even though `3.0 == 3` is True, `OddQ[3.0]` is False, because 3.0 has Head Float.

**Commentary**

Whilst the functions OddQ, etc. are described accurately, this behaviour may not be expected and therefore its effects hard to spot, and in my opinion it runs counter to the general feature of the language that the application of a function to a type for which it is undefined returns the function expression unevaluated, which does not happen with OddQ.

Since this is noted in the documentation under Possible Issues (where application of FullSimplify is consequently recommended), there is probably some good reason for the way that OddQ etc. work but I have no information on that; any link to an explanation would be welcome

```
(* MMA returns an expression unevaluated if it is not defined for that type *)
f[x_Integer]:=4 x;
f["1"]
(* f["1"] *) 
(* But OddQ and the like return False instead *)
OddQ["1"]
(* False *)
```

@domen's link to the [TestingExpressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TestingExpressions.html) documentation should also be noted; it says there

> Functions that "ask a question" have names that end in Q. They return
> True for an explicit true answer, and False otherwise.

where we see "explicit" used apparently synonymously with "manifestly", neither of which are immediately meaningful IMO, serving only to confirm what one *might* already know.